# Disable generation of cypress folders when running tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cypress

I'm trying to do a bunch of unit tests with Cypress. Here's the npm script that runs them:

`cypress run --project tests/unit/ --headless`

When I run them, it generates the typical plugin/support/videos folders, but I don't need them. Is there any flag that disables the generation of these 3 folders when running the tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add these generated reports to a `.gitignore` file in the project's root like so:

```bash
# Cypress generated files #
######################
cypress.env.json
cypress.meta.json
cypress/logs/
cypress/videos/*
cypress/screenshots/*
cypress/integration/_generated/*
cypress/data/migration/generated/*.csv
cypress/fixtures/example.json
cypress/build/*
```

Now, these files will never be version-controlled.

You can also disable video recording with proper configuration in your `cypress.json` file like so: `"video": false`.

You can also do it with CLI by overriding your `cypress.json`.

Currently, there's no way to disable the generation of those files. However, you could remove them by when launching Cypress with an [`npm script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts) like so:

```json
"clean:launch:test": "rm -rf /cypress/movies && rm -rf /cypress/screenshots && cypress run --project tests/unit/ --headless"
```

Then you can run it like so: `npm run clean:launch:test`. It should remove those folders & launch Cypress's unit tests.

I suggest just adding them to `.gitignore` or configuring Cypress to trash them before each run. You can read about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files).

**`cypress.json` file:**

```json
trashAssetsBeforeRuns: true
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about the plugin and support folders? Is it possible to get rid of them?

Comment: There's no current way to disable the generation of those files. You either not version control them by adding them to `.gitignore` plus you can add an `npm script` to remove them & launch the unit tests. I have updated my answer. @nelodev

Answer (score 4):

To disable the creation of video and screenshots folder you can do like in the following command.

```
cypress run --config video=false,screenshotOnRunFailure=false
```

To remove plugin/support folders I think they are not generated with current Cypress version so you can just remove them and add to .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Video recording can be turned off entirely by setting video to false from within your configuration.

```
"video": false
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos#Videos

Comment: Thanks! But what about the plugin and support folders? Is it possible to get rid of them?